# Number of permutations of $[n]$ that have no increasing subsequence of length $k$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many permutations are there that have no increasing subsequence of length $k$. Alternatively, *lower bounds* are welcome.

For $k=3$, it is known that the answer is the Catalan number: $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n \choose n}$. For example, for $n=3$, $C_3=5$, and indeed only $(1,2,3)$ fails.

Are there nice closed forms for $k>3$? Lower bounds?

Comment: OIES entry for $k=4$: https://oeis.org/A005802. OIES entry for $k=5$: https://oeis.org/A047889

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks!